# How to serve a specific file node server

Tags: node.js

Let us say I have a directory with 2 files: c:\file1\index.html and c:\file1\test.html. I am trying to start a server with node js on a specific port. Now I used `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname)))` as the directory to serve the file. My question is how can I make it serve `c:\\file1\test.html` with the code I have right now it serves `c:\\file1\index.html`? Thanks in advance.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')

//loads index.html
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname)))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server up on port 3000'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

//specify public folder
app.use(express.static('file1'));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server up on port 3000'));
```